# Drupal: how to register a new user through a request sent by another server

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have 2 drupal websites on 2 different servers with 2 different domains.

Users only see website A and they can fill a form with their personal data.

When they submit the form, the data arrive to my email address. At this point I pass them the url of the website B.

Now, I want to automatically register them in the website B, when they fill the form on website A, instead of only sending me an email.

Is there a way to send a request to Drupal from another server with all users account fields in order to register them ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this in a variety of ways. The most customizable solution would be to start with the [Services module](http://drupal.org/project/services), which exposes core APIs (including user_save) as web services.

A second solution would be to user the [Deploy module](http://drupal.org/project/deploy), which is built on top of Services, but provides some automation around pushing users (and content) between Drupal sites.

A 3rd solution would be to use Feeds and PubSubHubbbub as [described here](http://developmentseed.org/blog/2010/mar/02/simple-sign-openid), in the section about syncronizing users.

Answer (score 0):

This is non-trivial.

You can create a module that creates the account remotely by accessing the MySQL server, and have it fire off on an *action* by of account creation on Server A.  This would require direct MySQL server access from server A to server B, and an understanding of the SQL required on that server to make a new account. This is more secure than the next idea.

Alternatively you could open a URL on Server B and create a module that accepts the user's data, say in JSON, and then parses it and creates a new user through Drupal.  See URL below.

http://www.michaelphipps.com/how-create-users-programmatically-drupal-6x

*Ideally* you would combine the two user DBs (see the setting.php for how to share DB tables between Drupal instances.)  But at this point you are probably past the ability to do this easily.

There is no simple solution to this problem, that I know of.

Comment: I like the second option "open a URL to accept user's data". I was wondering, in order to make it safer, if I could accept requests only from a specific ip. Could you give me more information to implement it ?

Comment: You could filter on IP address in your root level .htaccess to divert requests that do not come from you selected IP.  This is the best solution because header information that PHP uses can be forged more easily.  Without going into too much detail, rely on apache or a firewall for this rather than code in your module... unless you can't avoid it.  If you must use code, then you can simply check the request for where it comes from in php and reject other IPs.